# Condition for a particular matrix to be semi definite positive

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $B$ a symmetric $N\times N$ real matrix whose diagonal elements are equal to one, that is to say

- $B_{i,i}=1$, $\forall i = 1, \dots N$
- $B_{i,j} = B_{j,i}$, $\forall i,j = 1, \dots N$.
- $B_{i,j} \in\mathbb R$, $\forall i,j = 1, \dots N$.

Is it possible to find a condition on the elements $B_{i,j}$ which implies that $B$ is positive definite ?

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: There is the Sylvester Criterion, are you looking for something else?

Comment: Yes, I know. I wanted to find something directly on the $B_{i,j}$. But I am totally not sure that such a condition can be found.

Comment: Well, you could create a condition on the $B_{i,j}$ that would imply positive semi definiteness via the Greshgorin circle theorem, but that would only be a sufficient condition.

Comment: A sufficient condition can be enough for me if it is not too restricitve...

Comment: I don't see how to use this theorem here. This gives me that for any eigen value $x$ of $B$ is such that: $$|x-1|<\sum_{i=1 ; i\neq j}^N |B_{i,j}|, \ \forall i\in\{1\dots N\}.$$ I don't see how to derive a condition that imply that $x\geq 0$

Comment: If the main diagonal is positive, and the elements on the off diagonals are sufficiently small, the Greshgorin discs would show that the eigenvalues cannot be negative and hence would be positive semi definite.

Comment: Yes I see. If the $\sum_{i=1 ; i\neq j}^N |B_{i,j}|$ is less than 1 for all $i$, then $x$ is positive.